# HAProxy should not forward incoming request to down instance

Tags: ubuntu, cluster-computing, haproxy

In my scenario, I have 2 servers, both are communicating with HAProxy. When request comes in, HAProxy splits the request and send it to both the server in round robin method. If in any case my first instance gets down at that time HAProxy should come to know that one of the server is down and it should not forward any request to that server. It should only communicate with another server for every request.

Can anybody tell me how I can configure my HAProxy for above scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have 2 tomcats on 10.0.0.2 and 10.0.0.3, and on the tomcat /server/alive responds only when the tomcat instance is alive, then this could be the backend in your haproxy config:

```
backend tomcat-dev
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor
    option httpchk HEAD /server/alive HTTP/1.0
    timeout connect 10s
    timeout server 60s
    server server-tomcat-dev-1 10.0.0.2:8080 weight 1 maxconn 512 check
    server server-tomcat-dev-2 10.0.0.3:8080 weight 1 maxconn 512 check
```